# Swap through active windows in C#

Tags: c#, windows

How would I Alt tab like in C# without using SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}"); This doesn't work the way I want it to. I want to be able to scroll through all active windows in an alt tab manner without having to do that. Like uhh. lets say I press a button, and it alt tabs to the next window. Once that window is open I press the button again and instead of going to the previous window it would go to the next. How do I go about doing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lets say I press a button, and it alt tabs to the next window. Once that window is open I press the button again and instead of going to the previous window it would go to the next.

You want the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Escape</kbd> shortcut then.  It will "cycle" through the open windows as you'd like...try it out!